Using UIAutomator dumpWindowHierarchy in Kotlin tests
I'm writing some Android UI Tests with UIAutomator and want to take advantage of the UiDevice.dumpWindowHierarchy() function.
Right now I'm calling it and passing it a full path to the same location that I place dumps using adb shell uiautomator dump
This is the call: device.dumpWindowHierarchy("/<full-path>/window_dump.xml")
Where device is set device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
However in my test, when I hit that point in my code I get
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /<path>/window_dump.xml: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get this output? Everything I've' tried so far has failed.

You can use a byte array to avoid the file permission problems, like in this example: https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dtmilano/android/culebratester2/location/UiDevice.kt#L139.
After all, you probably are going to read the content of the file into a byte array to do something with it.
